# Is there a general thesaurus for conceptual fields?

Tags: learning, word-choice, writing

My question is about ways to find out about, or remind oneself of, related concepts. Say I'm writing an article and I'm stuck finding the right expression.

- I want to say that the author is confused about a concept, but I don't want to use the word "confused", for stylistic, syntactical or any other reasons. I would like to find other words like "muddle", "is not clear about", or "does not distinguish".
- I want to say that I reject an objection to a given view. I would like to find other expressions like "riposte", "rejoinder", but also sentence templates such as "Contra N.N., I hold that"
- What are different ways to express the concept *opposition*? "In contrast", "Whereas .., ...", "On the other hand".
- What are different ways to make an enumeration of arguments? "First, ...; Second, ...", "For one thing, ...", "for another", ....

What I'm looking for is similar to a thesaurus, but many of these reference works (such as [this one](http://www.thesaurus.com)) only list expressions of roughly the same lexical category: "contrast" -- "comparison", but not "despite the similarities, ..." etc. "By contrast" is not even listed. Often what you need is just to be pointed in the right direction. Is there anything - a dictionary, thesaurus, list of schematic sentences, web site, ... - that fits my description?

Comment: Interesting! What you need is perhaps a compendium of set phrases and idioms, organised thematically. I don't know of such a thing, but if you can find someone capable of compiling one, i'd be in for fifty quid on a [Kickstart](http://www.kickstarter.com/)!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure there is a thesaurus as complete as the one you are looking for.

I like [**Wordnik**](http://www.wordnik.com/), which included lots of **examples** for each word proposed, as well as [**related words**](http://www.wordnik.com/about) (and not just synonyms or antonyms).
But the results remain close to the ones found with [www.thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/) (thesaurus that you mention in your question).

Comment: The visual thesaurus is also very interesting, but not free. http://www.visualthesaurus.com/landing/?ad=ddc.large&utm_medium=large&utm_campaign=VT&utm_source=ddc&word=confused&lang=en

Comment: Thanks, both are interesting, though as you say they don't really belong to a different category than a conventional thesaurus, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

This [reference source](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/) is a thesaurus, dictionary, encyclopedia, and a specialist reference all at the same place, so it might help.